# How to apply Teams app setup policy to users in CSV file using PowerShell?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Using PowerShell script how can we apply the policy to all users in the CSV file. Does the script require Skype for Business online PowerShell module?

Answer (score 0):

Using the below PowerShell script, we can apply the policy to all users in the CSV file. This script only required Skype for Business online PowerShell module.

This script will be useful if there is no AD group created specifically for a set of business units where the App needs to be displayed.

In the Governance point of view, the admin would need to run this PowerShell script incrementally.

```
   function Apply-TeamsAppPolicyUsingCSV
        {  
        param (  
       $ImportPath,$AppSetupPolicyName
       )  
        process{
            $cred = Get-Credential
            #login into Skype online powershell module
            $session = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $cred
            Import-PSSession $session

            #Get user information from csv file.
            $users = Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath

            #Add user to App setup policy
            foreach($user in $users)
            {
            Grant-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy -PolicyName $AppSetupPolicyName -Identity $user.EmailAddress
            Write-Host "Policy successfully added to $($user.EmailAddress) user " 
            } 
        }
   }

  Apply-TeamsAppPolicyUsingCSV -ImportPath c:\Userslist.csv -AppSetupPolicyName "Devteam policy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code used to add users from CSV to team policy. The loop will skip if there is any issue with the specific user by try-catch.

```
          $Logfile = "D:\TeamsAppPolicyScriptLog.log"

          function Apply-TeamsAppPolicyUsingCSV {  
              param (  
                    $ImportPath, $AppSetupPolicyName
                    )  
            process {
            Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
            $cred = Get-Credential
            #login into Skype online powershell module
            $session = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $cred
            Import-PSSession $session

            try {
                #Get user information from csv file.
                $users = Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath

                #Add user to App setup policy
                foreach ($user in $users) {
                    try {
                        Grant-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy -PolicyName $AppSetupPolicyName -Identity $user.EmailAddress
                        LogWrite "Policy successfully added to $($user.EmailAddress) user " 
                    }
                    catch {
                        LogWrite "Error in adding Policy added to $($user.EmailAddress) user " 
                        LogWrite $_.Exception.Message`n
                    }
                }
            }
            Catch {

                    LogWrite $_.Exception.Message`n
            }

        }
   }


   Function LogWrite
   {
    Param ([string]$logstring)

    Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
   }

 Apply-TeamsAppPolicyUsingCSV -ImportPath d:\Userslist.csv -AppSetupPolicyName "Teams App Policy Test"
```